# Query to replace partial values in an array of int in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

In PotgreSQL, how do I write a query to replace some values in an int4 array?

{1,2,10} -> {1,2,999}

{2,3,10} -> {2,3,999}

is what we are aiming for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you want to replace 10 with 999, you can use `array_replace`

```
array_replace(your_column, 10, 999)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Since I want to update table, query as follows seems to do

`update table set column = array_replace(column, 10, 999);`